# IIS 7 resource kit

Tags: iis-7

Is there a resource kit for IIS 7 (like [the IIS 6 res kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&displaylang=en))? If so, where can I get it from, I can't find it anywhere.

Specifically, I'm after the SelfSSL tool...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is no IIS 7 Resource Kit. It hasn't been released yet.